NextJs-14 How to solve my code can run when it declares 'use server' but it's error when 'use client'
I want to add function to this page it's needed to change to 'use client' but when I change it it's error. My stripe key need only use in server. I have tried to create new file and import it but it's still error when I 'use client'
Here my code
 async function ProductPage({params}) {

  const inventory = await stripe.products.list({ // need to use server only
    expand: ['data.default_price'], 
  });

  const products = inventory.data.map(product => { 
    const price = product.default_price
    return {
      currency: price.currency,  
      id: product.id,
      name: product.name,
      price: price.unit_amount,
      image: product.images[0]
    }
  })
    const product = products.find(product => product.id === params.id)
    console.log(product);

and this I try to import and inventory. But when I use 'use client' It error the same issue.
import { inventory } from '../Stripedatapage';

 async function ProductPage({params}) {

  const products = inventory.data.map(product => { 
    const price = product.default_price
    return {
      currency: price.currency,  
      id: product.id,
      name: product.name,
      price: price.unit_amount,
      image: product.images[0]
    }
  })
    const product = products.find(product => product.id === params.id)
    console.log(product);

here this error
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `StaticGenerationSearchParamsBailoutProvider`.
